# ScheduledExecutorService wait to perform tasks before the countdown to the next

Tags: java, java-8

There is a little example:

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().test();
    }

    public void test() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            print("Pre");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            print("Post");
        }, 2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Start relax time every time that work time is over
    }

    private void print(String m) {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " / " + m);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
39:35 / Pre
39:39 / Post
39:39 / Pre
```

My problem is that the *time until the next task* starts counting until the completion of the *previous one*.
So, what i want to see in output:

```
39:35 / Pre
39:39 / Post
39:41 / Pre
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think you're looking for `scheduleAtFixedDelay` instead of `scheduleAtFixedRate` then.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach `scheduleWithFixedDelay`* . So simple, thanks :)